# Need logic to allocate memory for nested structures

Tags: data-structures, linked-list, structure

I am not able to allocate memory for nested structures using pointers.
What syntax should I use to allocate the memory for lots of structures that have pointers to other structures? How should I go about accessing the values in the structures once the memory is allocated?

```
struct A {
    int *a;
    struct B *b;
};

struct B {
    int *b;
    struct C *c;
};

struct C {
    int *c;
    struct D *d;
};

struct D {
    int *d;
};

int main(int argc, const char* argv[]) {
    struct A* foo;

    /* Structure allocation */
    /* use of structures */
}
```

I can't go beyond 2 nested structures. Beyond that I start getting Segmentation fault.

I tried something like this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

typedef struct file f1;
typedef struct command c1;
typedef struct arguments a1;
typedef struct ccity ccity;
typedef struct csub csub;

struct arguments {
    char *argname;
    struct arguments *next;
};

struct command {
    char *cmdname;
    struct arguments *args;
};

struct file{
    int fileid;
    char *filename;
    struct command *cmd;
};

struct sub{
    char *subname;
};

struct city {
    char *city_name;
    struct sub *s11;
};

struct road{
    char *name;
    struct city *next_city;
};

int main()
{  
    char name[] = "HELLO ";

    struct file *f1;
    struct city *c1 = NULL;
    struct road *r1 = NULL;
    struct sub *s1 = NULL;

    printf("HELOOOOOOOOO");
    f1->filename;
    f1 = malloc(10*sizeof(struct file ));
    f1->filename = (char *)malloc(10*sizeof(char *));
    c1 = malloc(sizeof(c1));
    r1 = malloc(sizeof(r1));
    s1 = malloc(sizeof(s1));

    r1->name = malloc(100*sizeof(char *));
    r1->next_city = malloc(100*sizeof(r1->next_city));

    c1->city_name = malloc(100*sizeof(char *));
    c1->s11 = malloc(100*sizeof(c1->s11));

    c1->s11->subname  = calloc(120,sizeof(char*));
    (*c1).s11->subname = "text";

    (*r1).next_city->s11->subname = 
        malloc(10 * sizeof((*r1).next_city->s11->subname));

    strncpy((*r1).next_city->s11->subname,"sant",4);

    r1->name = malloc(sizeof(char *));
    c1->city_name = malloc(sizeof(char *));

    r1->next_city = malloc(sizeof(char *));
    r1->next_city->city_name = "Hello";

    /*strcpy(f1->filename,"file1");
    printf("name is %s\n",(f1->filename));

    c1->cmdname = (char *)malloc(10*sizeof(c1->cmdname));
    strcpy(f1[0].cmd[0].cmdname,"command1");
    printf("name is %s\n",f1[0].cmd[0].cmdname);

    strcpy(f1[0].cmd[1].cmdname,"command2");
    printf("name is %s\n",f1[0].cmd[1].cmdname);

    strcpy(f1[0].cmd[2].cmdname,"command3");
    printf("name is %s\n",f1[0].cmd[2].cmdname);

    strcpy(f1[0].cmd[2].args[0].argname,"argument1");
    printf("name is %s\n",f1[0].cmd[2].args[0].argname);

    strcpy(f1[0].cmd[2].args[0].argname,"argument1");
    printf("name is %s\n",f1[0].cmd[2].args[1].argname);

    (f1[0].cmd[0].args[0]).argname = malloc(20*sizeof(char*));
    strcpy((f1[0].cmd[0].args[0]).argname,"argument1");

    printf("name is %s\n",(f1[0].cmd[0].args[0]).argname);
    */
}
```

Comment: Can you provide your attempt at memory allocation. We won't be able to help you fully unless we can see were things break down.

Comment: Re-worded as best I can, updated the code snippet to hint to the author where they could include some more example code to better explain the issue.

Comment: Hi, I added code on your request. Please have a look .